# Multiple Instance of Activity Out of memory

Tags: android, android-intent, memory-leaks

I have an out of memory problem.

I have a suite of activities and a class across across the application.

I set the `launchMode` to `SingleTop` and the `noHistory` to true in the manifest for each activity.
I also set `android: largeHeap = "true"`

One main and five other activities I call A, B, C, D, E

A, B, C always show a single instance in the HEAP but D and E increase the number of instances each time the new Intent and its startActivity

C uses the same objects (listview, hashmap, simpleAdapter) also used in D and E

This happens:

Main boot, then boot C, C call D and D call E and return to C. C always has one instance while D and E instruct their instances by occupying 1 MB each time, eventually causing an Oom to superimposition Of 174Mb available for my App.

For all activities I run this code, for example from activityB, startC, activityC.

```
Intent activityC = new Intent (getBaseContext, activityC.class); // Try too getApplicationContext, activityC.this but instances remain anyway.

activityC.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // I try too SINGLE_TOP, NEW_TASK, CLEAR_TASK same result

Finish (); // I also tried to call finish () after startActivity () with the same result
startActivity (activityC);
```

It was all worthless.

I also use a `freeMemory()` function that invokes `onDestroy()` of each activity but with or without changes nothing

```
Public void freeMemory () {

System.runFinalization ();
Runtime.getRuntime (). Gc ();
System.gc ();

}
```

I've already tried to implement `onNewIntent` but I never get it.

In D and E `onDestroy` I tried to set null all objects (private) created in `onCreate()` but unsuccessful.

At the moment I'm trying with an Asus and Android 5.02 tablet.

Do not use Handler, Timer or AsyncTask.

For how much effort I did (I've really tried a lot) A, B, C always show a single instance in the HEAP while D and E

I also created a demo to try to focus the problem but I did not get results. In the SINGLE_TOP demo, you work as you expect and keep one instance per activity beyond the number of times it repeats.

What can retention of new instances?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".TEST"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityA"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityE"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityD"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityC"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityB"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />


    <activity android:name=".TempActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true"
        />
</application>

</manifest>
```

I noticed that when you switch from an activity to the other logcat tell me:
08-26 08: 22: 33.607 905-5207 /? W / ActivityManager: startActivity called from finishing ActivityRecord {6d2eb11 u0 danielezampieri.TEST / .ActivityC t472 f}; Forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent {flg = 0x24020000 cmp = danielezampieri.TEST / .ActivityD}
Because? What does this mean? Could it be because ActivityC generates multiple instances?

However, I commented on the finish () method after startactivity and only the activities mentioned above show multiple instances.

**UPDATE!!**
I focused the point that generates the problem. Thanks to your suggestions in any case.
In activityC (the one that displays multiple instances and occupies useless memory) I have two classes that extend Dialog, created them in the oncreate of activity with

```
newmydialog1 = New mydialog1 (this)
newmydialog1 = New mydialog2 (this)
```

Then I call

```
newmydialog1.show
```

In mydialog1 there is a button running

```
newmydialog2.show
```

If I run mydialog2, I do not create the multiple instance of activityC unless I press the button that runs mydialog2 here is the memory leak on activityC that believes each created instance.
I tried calling newmydialog2.cancel / dismiss and then set newmydialog2 to null before mydialog1's cancel () but nothing.
What else can I do?

Comment: post your manifest please

Comment: It is also likely that the reason your instances of D and E are not going away is because something is holding a reference to them. To check this, run your app, go from C to D to E and back a few times. Then take a heap dump to see how many instances of C, D and E you have in the heap. Also do `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` and look at the list of activities in your task.

Comment: I recommend implementing LeakCanary to help track down your memory leak: https://github.com/square/leakcanary. Also, if you run the 'lint' Gradle task, do you get any warnings for storing Context values in member/static variables? My guess is that a Context variable is getting stored as a hard reference somewhere and that is causing Activities to not get garbage collected.

Comment: Also, is your app a native app or are you loading HTML content into a WebView? If I remember correctly, there was a defect pre-Marshmallow where any Activity that used a WebView would not get garbage collected properly.

Comment: No, is not a native app (JNI) and not use WebView

Comment: @Bradford2000 I tryed LeakCanary but I receive the message "Dumping memory, app will freeze. Brrr" and not dump memory file. I try again.

Comment: @Bradford2000 leakcanary not show any memory leak!

Comment: After it says dumping memory, does a notification show up at the top the screen? Are you navigating through the activities that are causing issues? Also, if your project makes use of fragments, you'll want to register those as well so that LeakCanary can watch to see if those get cleaned up. They have a good example here: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-it

Comment: @Bradford2000 see my update. Thank's!

Comment: `Dialog`s are linked to the `Activity` that creates them. They should go away when the owned `Activity` goes away. If the garbage collector isn't reclaiming your `Activity`, there must be a reference to that `Activity` stored somewhere else.

Comment: If you have a heap dump that shows multiple instances of `ActivityC`, then you should be able to walk the heap dump to see where those references are located. Keep walking back until you find a live object that is holding a reference that is preventing the garbage collector to reclaim the instances of `ActivityC`.

Comment: @DavidWasser thank's to suggest. Yes I have a heap dump via Android studio memory monitor. I find it difficult to find what you are pointing to.
However I found the solution. See my next update and suggest me how to find in heap dump because I have not success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLUTION**

The new istance of mydialog2 must be in mydialog1 class and before the newmydialog2.show().

Answer (score 0):

If C & D & E share the same objects why don't you make ActivityC have a `ViewFlipper` to "flip" between your contents of C & D & E, and if you have alot of images try to scale them down or re-use them instead of creating them each time ... and if you are worried about lagging when flipping views try to use Async-task to, for example, create contents of D when the Activity is created... Also using `RecyclerViews` could be helpful instead of `ListViews`..... I hope I helped u in something :)

Comment: +1 reusing/recycling images. You can do this pretty easily with LruCache: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html

Comment: @haikal not depending from image e not have same object from activiy a part the class over application. See my update.